# What are allusions?

Tags: allusion

I do not understand how allusions 'indirectly' mention something. I have looked at examples of allusions, and the allusions I have seen seem to directly mention something. The site below: http://www.softschools.com/examples/grammar/allusion_examples/115/
has a list of allusions. Can someone please explain allusions to me?

Comment: The dictionaries disagree over this one. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/allusion) has a broader definition for the term as usually used in the UK, not demanding the '**indirectly** referencing' restriction:    '**allusion**
noun [ C ] UK ​ ... _something that is said or written that is intended to make you think of a particular thing or person_ Their definition for the usual US usage is in between: '_a brief or indirect reference_:
He made some allusion to the years they lived apart.'

Comment: "Please explain allusion" is too broad. You have found a site which [supposedly] does that. What **specifically** do you not understand about what it says? Have you looked for any other examples or teaching?

Comment: The site you link to uses the tighter, 'indirect reference' sense. eg 'Your backyard is a Garden of Eden.' rather than 'Your backyard must be a bit like the Garden of Eden mentioned in Genesis: everything orderly and beautifully arranged, with no signs of death or decay, no weeds or biting insects.' [Possibly a snake.]

Comment: @AndrewLeach Yes, the question is problematic, but your request is difficult to reply to. That's the point, they don't understand it. It's difficult to say what it is they don't understand because they don't understand. That's the nature of not understanding.

Comment: In general, an "allusion" means something a little less "solid" than a metaphor, and often harder to identify.  Eg, I might use the words "When, in the course of ..." and be *alluding* to the *Declaration of Independence*, or I might simply have chosen to use those words because they fit my intent.  Usually recognizing an allusion requires knowledge beyond that of the immediate topic, since the whole idea is to "light up" thoughts and memories that are stashed in the back of the brain and which might not otherwise be considered pertinent to the topic.

Comment: (Net-net:  The meaning of *allusion* is difficult to understand because even experts can't clearly describe it -- the meaning is rather ethereal.)

Comment: Can someone allude to something by accident?

Comment: I've heard the phrase "unintentional allusion" used occasionally, when a speaker said something that called up an image or memory which he likely did not intend.

Comment: @Mitch Well, it would be possible to say "but *is a Garden of Eden* **is** a direct reference, surely?" at least. And probably more.

Comment: Latterly, **any** reference to something or someone, direct or indirect, explicit or implicit, in passing or not, verbal or otherwise, intentional or unintentional, is an 'allusion'. I, for example, have just alluded to 'allusion'. Your question, however, implies that you're trying to understand what a *particular type* of 'allusion', perhaps a *literary allusion*, is. For us or anyone to help with that, you need to specify the type of allusion you want to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of an allusion that seems to me to be fairly indirect:

> Stanley is flying a kite on a cloudy day. Ollie walks up to him and says, "Caught any electricity yet, Ben?"

The allusion here is to Benjamin Franklin and more specifically to his [famous experiment](http://www.ushistory.org/franklin/info/kite.htm) involving a kite and a key, conducted (so to speak) during a thunderstorm. In the allusion above, the kite, the key, the thunderstorm, the lightning, and the full name *Benjamin Franklin* all go unmentioned. To understand what Ollie is alluding to, you have to recognize that "Ben" refers to Franklin and then you have to recognize that Ollie is drawing a connection between Franklin's experiment and Stanley's kite flying on a cloudy day.

This is how allusions work in day-to-day situations—and often, as here, they only hint at the thing they allude to. You might argue that "Ben" is a direct reference to Benjamin Franklin; but taken at face value in the original sentence, "Ben" functions as a term of address to Stanley. In another situation, Ollie might use that same term of address to equate Stanley's behavior with that of, say, the [leader of a band of killer rats](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068264/). Ollie's statement doesn't make sense unless you get the allusion.

Comment: Ah. Another fine mess.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Truly, we live in a world of allusion.

Comment: @AndrewLeach [Laurel and Hardy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Fine_Mess)? (Trying to find the connection.)

Comment: This would be a good answer, but the OP is asking about a particular, but *unspecified* type of allusion (possibly, in this case, an 'indirect allusion', or 'indirect historical allusion'), and you're answering as if the type of 'allusion' at issue *has been specified*. See my comment (and close-vote) on the question.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes, although I was thinking of their short films which used to appear on TV and which I seem to have [misquoted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurel_and_Hardy#Catchphrases). I don't *think* Sven's quote actually appeared on film. His reply appears to have originated [in around 1829](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=VVU_AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22we+live+in+a+world+of+illusion%22&source=bl&ots=h6thTa4BRE&sig=9zg20bYd3wjhHS08vs1LfN7Gels&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYouaIsKzOAhXMBsAKHYI2D6oQ6AEIKDAD#v=onepage&q=%22we%20live%20in%20a%20world%20of%20illusion%22%20original&f=false).